# Importing Apache POI cell library

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

I am writing a project, and the results should be saved to Excel file (`.xlsx`).
I added the following dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.8-beta3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.16-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

All the imported libraries are working properly, such as:

```java
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

except the one related to cells. It must have the following imported statement:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
```

But it does not work. I do not know what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204) - **Mixing POI jars between releases is not supported**.

You should change your pom to refer to the same, latest version of Apache POI for everything, eg

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>3.16-beta1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>3.16-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

With that in place, you'll be able to access the [Cell class](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) without issues

Answer (score 0):

If you download [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.16-beta1) jar (that's what you have specified in your pom.xml), you will see that the `Cell` class is there, so the problem must lie elsewhere e.g. IDE caches (for IntelliJ try reimporting maven projects, for Eclipse -- don't know unfortunately).

Comment: I am using NetBeans

Comment: I don't know how to clear NetBeans dependency caches, but your pom.xml looks good and `Cell` class is in the jar.

Comment: Thank yo very much for your help. The problem is solved. There was another imported class in my code and cause the previous error.